# New base of matroid from old

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

Let $M$ be a matroid of rank 3 and $E_1, E_2, E_3$ 3 basis of $M.$ Let $e_{i,j}$ be the $i$-th element of base $E_j$.

> Is it true that you can always find a permutation $s: \{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2,3\}$ such that $e_{s(1),1}, e_{s(2),2}, e_{s(3),3}$ is also a base?

I could not find a counter example.

I am also interested in arbitrary rank (it is obviously false for a matroid of rank 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be the cycle matroid of the graph shown below.

[image: kite graph]

Consider this grid:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 2 5
```

Each row gives a basis for $M$.  However, no transversal gives a basis.